# Richfaces Skin Overriding Styleclass

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces, stylesheet

I have a JSF2/Richfaces 4 project in which I want to use one of the default skins, BUT I also want to set some things' style using my own custom style sheet. This sounds pretty straightforward, but what I am finding is that in at least some cases, my own style is not being used. To be explicit, here are my relevant web.xml context-params:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.control_skinning</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.control_skinning_classes</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My CSS file inclusion:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="jsp-css.css" library="css" />
```

One such actual style definition:

```
.obsOptBtnSel{
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url('/images/circleY.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
border: none;
text-align: center;
width: 2em;
height: 2em;
}
```

And the actual button using the style:

```
<h:commandButton
value="?"
styleClass="#{obs.observation.observationExtent == -1.0 ? 'obsOptBtnSel' : 'obsOptBtnUns'}"
id="unknownButton"
/>
```

So, one would think that I'd inherit the styles from the blueSky skin where relevant, and then since I'm specifying a style class, any properties mentioned in the custom style sheet would be overridden.

But instead, when I look at the element in Firebug, I see my styleClass getting overridden by that specified by the skin, e.g. it keeps using the blueSky background image instead of mine.

I know I could fix this by simply putting !important after all my styling in the stylesheet, but that seems like a really crappy and unnecessary way to deal with this problem.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RichFaces has already a default background specified on the `input[type=submit]` CSS selector which is a stronger selector than `.obsOptBtnSel`. There are basically 2 options:

1. Rename your selector to `input[type=submit].obsOptBtnSel` to make it yet stronger.

   ```
   input[type=submit].obsOptBtnSel {
       background-color: transparent;
       background-image: url('/images/circleY.gif');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: center;
       border: none;
       text-align: center;
       width: 2em;
       height: 2em;
   }
   ```

   *Note, those 4 background properties can be set as a `background` oneliner with the sub-properties in the order `color image position repeat`*:

   ```
   background: transparent url('/images/circleY.gif') center no-repeat;
   ```
2. Add `!important` to the background properties to override all non-`!important` properties on the same element set by other CSS selectors.

   ```
   .obsOptBtnSel {
       background-color: transparent !important;
       background-image: url('/images/circleY.gif') !important;
       background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
       background-position: center !important;
       border: none;
       text-align: center;
       width: 2em;
       height: 2em;
   }
   ```

   *or, shorter,*

   ```
   background: transparent url('/images/circleY.gif') center no-repeat !important;
   ```

Comment: Balus wins again! And I learned something new about CSS. I was under the impression that the more specific styling would always win out in an override scenario, but that is clearly not the case. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. To get a better understanding of CSS precedences, I think this article is a good read: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: And is there a way to include our own css files **after** richfaces ones in the head ? At same CSS selector level, it could override richfaces ones...

Comment: More specific CSS does win but the math on how CSS selectors work uses a specific group multiplier algorithm that can a little complex to understand at first. The `!important` declaration trumps otherwise. This must be used in moderation though as the more `!important` definitions, then everything becomes important and thus ... NOTHING is important at a certain point.